# Retornar valores duplicados em arrays

Tags: php

Minha duvida é a seguinte?
Tenho os seguintes array:

```
$array1 = array(10, 50, 80, 40, 90);
$array2 = array(10, 30, 10, 40, 20);
$array3 = array(10, 60, 15, 40, 30);
$array4 = array(20, 30, 40, 10, 50);
$array5 = array(10, 05, 10, 90, 40);
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma simples de percorrer todos e retornar somente os valores que se repetem em todos os arrays.

Para pegar os valores duplicados do mesmo array estou usando:

```
$unArray = array_unique( array_diff_assoc( $idCliArray, array_unique( $idCliArray ) ) )
```

Agora preciso saber como pegar somente o que se repete em todos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-intersect.php), exemplo:

```
$array1 = array(10, 50, 80, 40, 90);
$array2 = array(10, 30, 10, 40, 20);
$array3 = array(10, 60, 15, 40, 30);
$array4 = array(20, 30, 40, 10, 50);
$array5 = array(10, 05, 10, 90, 40);

$values = array_intersect($array1,$array2,$array3,$array4,$array5);
```

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/eckTC4)**

Comment: Obrigado, @abfurlan, isso me deu um norte