# Verificar se existem numeros repetidos entre dois arrays php

Tags: php, array

Ola,
tenho dois arrays em php e preciso verificar se existe algum numero no array 1 que repete com algum numero no array 2.  Não preciso dos numeros, so preciso saber se repete! Como fazer?

Comment: [Essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149752/retornar-valores-duplicados-em-arrays/149756#149756) pergunta deve responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a função [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) do `php`:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Neste caso, ele retornará tudo o que contém nos dois `arrays` mantendo suas `chaves`:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Você pode utilizar ou criar outra função que utilize este médoto como for melhor pra sua regra.

Comment: Perfeito cara. Era isso mesmo!!! Vlw!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `array_intersect`

```
<?php

   $array1 = array("a" => "verde", "vermelho", "azul");
   $array2 = array("b" => "verde", "amarelo", "vermelho");
   $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
   print_r($result);

?>
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [a] => verde
    [0] => vermelho
)
```